# Font recommendations for text recognition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm using google vision API for detecting names and numbers on running bibs. See below for a typical image. Any pointers of font or layout that would give the best detection result?

[image]

Comment: If you are close to organizers I would recommend to print not just digits but also QR codes and then use not Google Vision but smth else for new, more trivial problem.